# WPF animation issue on button click

Tags: wpf, animation, button

I would like to show some animation of button, before click event of button is fired. I am using following XAML to achieve that but it seems like `Button.IsPressed` trigger is getting fired after click event.

How to set trigger so it will show animation first before click event?

```
<Button x:Name="button" 
        Width="131" 
        Height="37" 
        Content="Button" 
        Margin="0,0,0,22" 
        Click="button_Click">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed"  Value="True">
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                                 From="130" 
                                                 To="0" 
                                                 Duration="0:0:2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

**EDIT:** I tried this but same thing.

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" 
                             From="130" 
                             To="0" 
                             Duration="0:0:2"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention when exactly you want the animation to start but you could try and use [PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmouseleftbuttondown.aspx)

Comment: It's button of datagrid which basically delete column. so before it gets deleted, i want to show some animation (change width of button from 130 to 0) and then delete whole column. Animation is perfectly there, only thing is I have to call before it goes to code behind to delete actual column

Comment: This sounds like a race condition. It would be better to start the animation in code behind and pause execution until the storyboard has finished. If you do not do this, chances are the row will be deleted before the animations has ended. I am not aware of a correct event/override for this purpose but you might try OnExecutedDelete